# How to handle Crypto library provider support differences between environments?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle

Using `javax.crypto`, the following code fails when using Oracle's JDK (SunJCE?), but is fine with IBM's JDK (IBMJCE?):

```
String asymPadding = "RSA2048/ECB/OAEPWithSHA256AndMGF1Padding";
String secKeyEncoded = getSymmetricKey(secKey);
KeyPair keyPair = getKeyPair(SELF4);

if (asymmPadding.contains(RSA2048)) {
    asymmPadding = RSA.concat(asymmPadding.substring(asymmPadding.indexOf("/")));
}

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(asymPadding);
```

The error thrown at the cipher call:

`Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA256AndMGF1Padding`

Does this mean I will need to write my encryption/decryption using a different provider, like Bouncy Castle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java SE supports `"RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding"` - including dash - instead of `"RSA2048/ECB/OAEPWithSHA256AndMGF1Padding"` excluding dash. Java doesn't automatically remove the dash or anything like that, which means that the string `"OAEPWithSHA256AndMGF1Padding"` for the padding is not recognized. Simply remove the dash and see if it works on both runtimes.

The strings supported by the various cryptography related classes can be viewed in the ["Java Cryptography Architecture Standard Algorithm Name Documentation (for JDK 8)"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Cipher).

Comment: I've created a working version of your code. Please update your question to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Could you also indicate if the IBM JRE supports the string *with* the dash in the comments below my answer please?

Comment: Thank you Maarten!  Yes, the IBM JRE does support it with the dash, but the same code on Oracle's JRE is failing with Wrong key size.  I will add an MCVE shortly.

Comment: Did you install the unlimited cryptography files for the Oracle JRE? That's often the first stumble block (in that case the `Cipher` class itself will throw an error rather than a class that implements `CipherSpi`...) Anyway, that's in the `init` method so problem solved, I presume.

Comment: Yes, I've installed the JCE for all three versions i have, the wrong key size is happening during the decryption only, the Cipher init calls during encryption is fine.  Now that i think about it, I believe my original question has been answered, and this new issue most likely requires its own thread, if i can't figure it out.  thanks!